# Select the first record of a query with an in condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with information like this:

```
COD_FICHERO,FECHA,ID_VERSION,CODIGO_FRONTERA,FACTOR_PERDIDAS
TFROC,2023-10-23 00:00:00.000,2,Frt5125,1.32993586654688
TFROC,2023-10-04 00:00:00.000,2,Frt0054,1.1361400284643
TFROC,2023-10-09 00:00:00.000,2,Frt4917,1.13871246571916
TFROC,2023-10-03 00:00:00.000,2,Frt2604,1.44391785864422
TFROC,2023-10-27 00:00:00.000,2,Frt2007,1.21119103377573
```

The columns that interest me are CODIGO_FRONTERA and FACTOR_PERDIDAS.
For the same CODIGO_FRONTERA there are several records since there are many dates, however I am only interested in the last date.
Then, I naively thought this would solve my problem:

```
SELECT TOP(1) CODIGO_FRONTERA, FACTOR_PERDIDAS
FROM analiticaitsqldw.app.tyd_bdmen_tfroc tba
WHERE CODIGO_FRONTERA IN ('FRT49161',
    'Frt00270',
    'Frt00338',
    'Frt45847',
    'Frt46655')
AND ID_VERSION = '2'
ORDER BY FECHA DESC;
```

But as is obvious, I only bring a single record but not the last record for each "BORDER_CODE". How can I achieve this efficiently?

Comment: BORDER_CODE? Translate all or none occurrences.

Comment: pop this in a subquery: `RID = row_number() over (partition by CODIGO_FRONTERA order by FECHA desc)` then select the rows `where RID = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the last record for each "BORDER_CODE," you can use a common table expression (CTE) with the `ROW_NUMBER` window function to rank the rows based on the `FECHA` column in descending order for each "BORDER_CODE." Then, you can filter the results to select the records with a row number of 1 for each "BORDER_CODE." Here's the SQL query to achieve this efficiently:

```sql
WITH RankedRecords AS (
  SELECT
    CODIGO_FRONTERA,
    FACTOR_PERDIDAS,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODIGO_FRONTERA ORDER BY FECHA DESC) AS rn
  FROM analiticaitsqldw.app.tyd_bdmen_tfroc tba
  WHERE CODIGO_FRONTERA IN ('FRT49161', 'Frt00270', 'Frt00338', 'Frt45847', 'Frt46655')
    AND ID_VERSION = '2'
)

SELECT CODIGO_FRONTERA, FACTOR_PERDIDAS
FROM RankedRecords
WHERE rn = 1;
```

In this query:

1. The `ROW_NUMBER` window function is used to assign a row number to each row within each "BORDER_CODE" group based on the `FECHA` column in descending order (`ORDER BY FECHA DESC`). This creates a ranked list of records for each "BORDER_CODE."
2. The `PARTITION BY` clause in the `ROW_NUMBER` function ensures that the ranking is done separately for each "BORDER_CODE."
3. The CTE `RankedRecords` contains the ranked records.
4. In the final `SELECT` statement, you filter the records with a row number equal to 1 for each "BORDER_CODE," which represents the last record for each group.

This query efficiently retrieves the last record for each "BORDER_CODE" based on the specified criteria.

Comment: Great answer, but you need to try and avoid providing new answers when there are existing answers to common problem.

Comment: @Dale K: The index of suspicion for a (purely) [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar)-generated answer is high on this one.